# MySQL: Group by select first 2 rows in each group

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to select first 2 answers for each Qs from answers table:

user_answers Table structure:

```
id    question_id    user_id    answer_id    create_date
1         1             9           5            null
2         2             8           7            null
3         1             1           3            null
4         3             4           20           null
5         1             4           5            null
6         4             3           25           null
7         2             7           5            null
8         4             9           26           null
9         2             5           8            null
10        1             1           5            null
```

I need to return results like this:

```
id    question_id    user_id    answer_id    create_date
1         1             9           5            null
3         1             1           3            null
2         2             8           7            null
7         2             7           5            null
4         3             4           20           null
6         4             3           25           null
8         4             9           26           null
```

It's like Group by "question_id" but select first 2 rows from each group,

thanks,

Comment: `first 2 rows` ... how are you defining "first" here?

Comment: table "id" column (ASC)

Comment: *"It's like Group by "question_id""* -- no, it's not like `GROUP BY`. `GROUP BY` **does not** return rows from the table; it **computes** the content of the rows it returns using the data from each group. This question belongs to the tag [tag:greatest-n-per-group]

Comment: thank for inform me, so is there anyway to handle it in MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way: (if you need more than 2 rows per group, then this is not solution)

```
select your_table.* from your_table
inner join(
    select min(id) as id from your_table group by question_id
    union all
    select min(id) as id from your_table
    where id not in (select min(id) from your_table group by question_id)
    group by question_id
) t
on your_table.id = t.id
order by your_table.question_id , your_table.id
```

Comment: Work fine, pls, how can I display first 3? rather than 2

Comment: Just not this )), for more than 2 rows per group, this query becomes very ugly and more inefficient, so if you need more than 2 rows per group, then this is not solution .

Comment: @mwafi: To get the minimums plus the minimums of all values except those minimums in order to get the first two minimums already feels a bit clumsy. And as Oto says himself: this gets more clumsy with more than two rows. You'd use a row numbering technique instead as shown in Tim's and my answer.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner - If needed just 2 first/last rows, this is probably one of most efficient way in mysql. About more than 2 rows, this is bad idea, I agree without doubt.

Comment: @Oto Shavadze: And I agree that the idea is good for two rows :-) It looks a bit clumsy, but does its task efficiently.

Answer (score 2):

This is a canonical problem where a `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function would be extremely useful.  MySQL does not support any row number functionality out of the box, but we can simulate it using session variables:

```
SET @row_num = 0;
SET @q_id = 0;

SELECT
    t.id,
    t.question_id,
    t.user_id,
    t.answer_id,
    t.create_date
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        @row_num:=CASE WHEN @q_id = question_id THEN @row_num + 1 ELSE 1 END AS rn,
        @q_id:=question_id as question_id,
        id,
        user_id,
        answer_id,
        create_date
    FROM
        user_answers
    ORDER BY question_id, id
) t
WHERE t.rn <= 2
ORDER BY t.question_id, t.id;
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: Run this Query on MySQL (phpMyadmin) "@row_num" variable always have: 1

Comment: @mwafi Hmm...it runs in the demo.  Try initializing with `SET @q_id = 0;` instead and see if that changes anything.  You may have to slightly tweak this query to get it to run in your environment.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple but rather slow solution: count the records.

```
select *
from answers
where
(
  select count(*)
  from mytable other
  where other.questionid = answers.questionid
  and other.id <= answers.id
) <= 2
order by questionid, id;
```

Comment: VERY slow indeed.  I ran a similar query to this method and it took 9 seconds.